# C++ design pattern help; Abstract classes with private access?

Tags: c++

I have a couple of 'strongly interdependent' class in C++ in a lib I'm writing. The first class is the "DataSet" and like its namesake, manages data. The second class is the "Renderer" and draws the data in DataSet. Both classes are abstract. Here's the 'flow' I want between the two classes:

- An application creates implemented DataSet objects (DataSetImpA,B,C) and passes them to the implemented Renderer (RendererImp).
- The application tells the Renderer where its camera is pointing.
- The Renderer calls a private 'update' method on each DataSet with the camera parameters so that the DataSets prepare all the relavent objects.
- The Renderer calls a private 'get' method to retrieve the newly prepared objects.
- The Renderer occasionally calls a private 'clear' method to destroy the DataSet's objects.

The 'update', 'get' and 'clear' methods would be pure virtual functions in DataSet. Friend classes don't work here because I want the implementation to be open and extensible for someone using the lib; expecting someone to write "friend class x"  when 'class x' varies based on the implementation to be used is bad.

Could someone suggest a method/design pattern to implement something like the above? Feel free to suggest a different way of doing things as well

Comment: Don't make your `update`, `get`, and `clear` methods `private`, make them `public`. Document them saying they are meant to be used by Renderers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why `update`, `get` and `clear` need to be `private`. To me, this looks like a bad design. If you're planning on calling them from other classes, and, logically, they should be called from other classes, make them `public`. In fact, I'd probably just make `update` private and call it internally from `DataSet` whenever required (for example, call it at the beginning of `get`).

You could do it the way you want by just making `Renderer` a friend, and accessing those methods just through renderer, but, to be honest, that doesn't look clean at all.

Comment: Well I was kind of torn between all the negative feedback on using friend classes and specifically marking methods as 'not for general use'. To me public implies you can use them whenever you want whereas in my case it only makes sense to use them from a renderer. Maybe I'm just being paranoid.

Answer (score 1):

Give the `DataSet` a public `render` function, and pass the `Renderer` to it.

If you need the update to be independent of rendering, make `update` public, too.

A good design principle is [Tell, Don't Ask](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask). Don't write getters, rearrange your design so that they are not needed.

The name `DataSet` hides the true meaning of the objects. They are visible, renderable, scene objects, props, solids.

It sounds as though you want to render a particular view of a scene, depending upon the camera position. The view is dynamic:

```
View view(scene);    
...
view.render(renderer);
```